# Mysql query efficient date calculation

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table as:

```
ID           RECORD_DATE              
1            2012-12-15 00:00:00      
2            2012-12-16 00:00:00      
3            2012-12-17 00:00:00      
4            2012-12-17 16:00:00
```

Now I need to calculate the time between the adjacent date, so it would look like:

```
start                  end                  difference
2012-12-15 00:00:00    2012-12-15 23:59:59  23:59:59
2012-12-16 00:00:00    2012-12-16 23:59:59  23:59:59
2012-12-17 00:00:00    2012-12-17 16:00:00  16:00:00
```

Is there any efficient way to do this kind of calculation on the database side?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. It can be efficiently done on the database side.

Comment: Can you explain the logic that deducts 1 second from the first two results, but not the third? Also, we like to see proper DDLs as well as the best efforts of the author to date.

Comment: TIMEDIFF() is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand what you said clearly but try this

```
SELECT t1.RECORD_DATE AS start,
       t2.RECORD_DATE AS end,
       TIMEDIFF(t2.RECORD_DATE,t1.RECORD_DATE) AS difference
FROM TABLE AS t1
JOIN TABLE AS t2 ON t1.id = (t2.id + 1);
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that the assumption of incremental ids is reasonable (although I accept that they *are* in the example provided above)

Comment: Even I am not happy with this query, but I wrote it assuming incremental id, although we can sort it by few changes in the query, Anyways thanks for the taking interest. :)

Comment: @RaghavPotluri I have just tested your query, and it provides the fast execution. Unfortunately I have to deal with the possibility of not having the incremental sequence. Thank you

Comment: @Adnan yes, I was writing with your example in mind.I'll try for a better answer.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind or query, using `TIME_DIFF()` :

```
SELECT
    start,
    end,
    TIMEDIFF(end, start) AS difference
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        t_start.record_date AS start,
        (
            SELECT 
                t_end.record_date
            FROM records AS t_end
            WHERE t_end.id > t_start.id
                    ORDER BY t_end.id
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS end
    FROM records AS t_start
) AS t_boundaries
```

Comment: ...assuming id is incremental (no gaps) - and that dates and ids never fall out of sequence

Comment: Just changed for `t_end.id > t_start.id`, to prevent missing entries to break everything.

Comment: Hm, now you need an ORDER BY (or a MIN... GROUP BY). Can we just use a simpler query?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to deal with adjacent rows when its not sequencial i.e. after id = 1 you may have 4 or 5 etc.

```
select 
t1.RECORD_DATE as `start`,
t2.RECORD_DATE as `end`,
TIMEDIFF(t2.RECORD_DATE, t1.RECORD_DATE) as difference
from table_name t1
join table_name t2 on t2.ID = (
                  select MIN(x.ID) 
                  from table_name x 
                  where x.id > t1.id
)
```

Also I have noticed you are taking the end date from `2012-12-16 00:00:00` to `2012-12-15 23:59:59` which is not as in the table so you may need to use `date_sub()` to deduct 1 second from the end date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
     , MIN(y.record_date - INTERVAL 1 SECOND) end
     , TIMEDIFF(MIN(y.record_date) - INTERVAL 1 SECOND,x.record_date) diff 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.record_date > x.record_date 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
```

If it matters, I guess some trick with an OUTER JOIN could deal with the missing second